# Session data disappear when using sess_use_database in codeigniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

Im creating a authentication for my web (currently im using codeigniter as my php framework).

How come when i set **TRUE** in the  `$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;`

my session data's disappears and doesn't display in part of the page. Im trying to display the username of the person who login to the site.

When the `$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;` the username displays in the page.

anyone experience this problem? how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create database table to store session data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar(50) NOT NULL,
last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
user_data text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
);
```

And then set `$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';`

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: i have setup that table as well as the $config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions'; 

the problem is when i set the $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE; the session data doesn't display but when i set it to FALSE. it does display again

Comment: Is the data in `ci_session` table?

Comment: what do you mean by "Is the data in ci_session table?" sorry can you please rephrase your question? thanks

Comment: When the user is logged in successfully, is there any data/rows in `ci_sessions` and are you loading `database` library from `autoload.php`? `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Comment: Now i got understand your question. When i try to login to the page  the datas in the 'ci_sessions' table, i noticed it that a new record appends. On my autoload.php, i load all the libraries, configs, helpers that i needed for the whole project.

Comment: Post some code, otherwise its very difficult to help you solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

In CodeIgniter 2, the ci_sessions table needs to be slightly different.

Specifically the size of user_agent has gone from varchar 50 to varchar 120. Make sure you use this basic prototype if you are using CodeIgniter 2 with `sess_use_database` set to TRUE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
user_data text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

via http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: This is exactly the problem I was having after upgrading a project to Code Igniter 2